# Do notation without monads: possible?

Tags: haskell, monads

I have a stateful type with the `>>` and `>>=` operators, which is nearly a monad. The intended use is to generate code for another language, and having the do-notation available will be very appropriate.

However, there is no well-defined return function, as values are only supposed to be produced along with side-effects. So, if I fake a return function, the return function should return an error only, and it breaks the monad laws. ( I.e. it is never valid to use a return function. )

What I observe is that the do-notation only sugars two operators, the `>>` and `>>=` operators.

Is there a way to retain something like the do notation for only those 2 operators, or something as clean as it, but without making a monad?

NOTE: Below the line are details that are not necessary for the question in the title. It's the context for why I asked the question, replies to which I'm interested in. Others who browse this topic would probably prefer to ignore it.

---

CORRECTION: I'm not generating code into an imperative language, although it shouldn't matter. I'm generating code into Javascript.

CLARIFICATION (in response to bdonlan): My type is (m a), which carries a state (which is the code to be generated given various parameters, similar to the state monad) and will return a value (the variable names in the generated code, with a haskell type attached). Thus, there shouldn't be a way to return values, which are associated with variable names, without generating code that defines the variable names. * This is solely due to my design, which might be inferior to others which I have not thought of.

In response to the responses: There seems to be two kinds of responses to this. First, is whether it is indeed possible, and perhaps the best way to go about using the do notation. The second is on whether it is better to use a monad, and define a return (or whether it even makes sense to not do so - perhaps at a later point in time, I would find that a return is required).

Example of what I would be doing:

```
data JsState = JsState { code :: String , vidCount :: Int } 
-- vidCount is for generating unique variable names

newtype JsStmt = JsStmt ( JsState -> JsState )

newtype JsMonad a = JsMonad ( JsState -> ( a , JsState ) )

def :: (JsValue a) => a -> JsMonad a

-- Outputs "var " ++ toUniqueVarName vidCount ++ " = " toCode a ++ ";"

-- Returns JsMonad with the variable name as the value,
-- with a type attached, and the JsState's vidCount is incremented by 1.


alertJsInt :: JsIntE -> JsMonad ()

-- Outputs something like "alert(" ++ toCode JsIntE ++ ");"

do
  x <- def $ JsIntL 2
  y <- def $ JsIntL 4
  alertJsInt (x + y)
```

Comment: Why can't you define a `return` function? You can't possibly define a no-op element in your type?

Comment: It's interesting to note that `return` is not really needed to express most things. In Scala you can write `for(x <- xs; y <- ys) yield x+y`, where `yield` looks similar to Haskell's `return`, but is a keyword. The entire construct is translated to something roughly equivalent to this Haskell: `xs >>= \x -> fmap (\y -> x+y) ys`.

Comment: @bdonlan: I can define a no-op element in my type, but I want a no-op element to always return nothing - not sure if that will be a problem later on.

Comment: It might be easier to comment on your design if you could give some examples of primitive operations in your type. I'm still having a hard time understanding why you need this restriction, and if I could see exactly what you're doing and some examples of how you're using it, I could give better advice.

Comment: @Dingfeng Quek: If you have a no-op at all then your restriction goes beyond just lacking `return`; you can't have `fmap` either.

Comment: @camccann: You can have `fmap` without a no-op. The trivial example would be a functor type with only `_|_` as a member.

Comment: @bdonlan: But he can't have `fmap` *and* a no-op here, because the two combined suffice to implement `return`.

Comment: @B&C: Agreed (I didn't intend any no-op to begin with). I'll need to flesh it out further - I'm taking the approach of only adding in the features I need as I code my JS modules, rather than specifying everything up-front. It seems likely that both of you are right, and that I will discover that using return, which makes it a monad, will be better. Thanks for both of your help!

Comment: @Dingfeng Quek: You should definitely take a look at the package I linked to in my answer. I'm inclined to think that what you're doing to generate identifiers is pretty directly analogous to the instances defined there for types like `IntMap`.

Comment: Your `def` function looks almost like a `return`, but it has a context.  Is that the problem?  I do not know how to solve it elegantly, but this looks like the same problem as “`Data.Set` cannot be a `Functor`.”

Comment: @Tsuyoshi Ito: Note that `def` generates a new identifier, which I assume means updating `vidCount`, whereas `return` is required to do nothing. `\x -> putStrLn "ce n'est pas une unité" >> return x` is not the same thing as `return :: a -> IO a`.

Comment: @camccann: Ah, now I see.  Indeed, using `def` as `return` does not satisfy the monad laws (assuming that `def` increases `vidCount`).  Thanks!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Well, the sort of structure you're working with does already exist; a [relevant type class can be found on Hackage](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/semigroupoids/1.2.2/doc/html/Data-Functor-Bind.html#g:4), in fact. I don't recommend trying to force it into an instance of `Monad`, though, for the reasons that bdonlan gives. The existence of `return` is pretty fundamental and you're likely to run into trouble everywhere trying to use standard functions for `Monad`s.

....however! That said, if you *really* want `do` notation, consider this quote [from the GHC user guide](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/users_guide/syntax-extns.html#rebindable-syntax):

> "Do" notation is translated using whatever functions (>>=), (>>), and fail, are in scope (not the Prelude versions).

...in other words, you're right that using `do` notation makes sense, because nowhere does it actually use `return` when desugared. That section is about the `RebindableSyntax` extension, which does exactly what it claims. If you don't mind giving up `do` notation for `Monad`, you can use that extension, define your own functions, and use `do` notation all you like.

Comment: Hm... how about a do notation where you can define the functions used?
do(>>=, >>, fail)  { ... ; ... } or 
do(myBind, myCompose, myFail)  { ... ; ... }.
That would be nice.

Comment: @Dingfeng Quek: `RebindableSyntax` doesn't require top-level definitions, it just cares what's in scope. Feel free to do `foo = do { ... } where (>>=) = ...` etc.

Answer (score 9):

The idiomatic solution would be to use two monads Writer and State - Writer to accumulate the code "String" and State to track the variable counter.

You can combine the two monads into one amalgamated monad if you don't want to use a monad transformer library:

```
-- There are better types to use rather than String...
type Output = String
type St  = Int

newtype JsMonad a = JSMonad { getJSMonad :: St -> (a, St, Output) }
```

[As you are using the standard combination of two standard monads the obvious definition of return and bind won't break the monad laws.]

This is quite a common pattern for building embedded DSLs that use the do-notation, see Andy Gill's Dot library on Hackage for instance. Oleg Kiselyov also has an XML library in this style (CSXML - not on Hackage).

As you don't care about about the final answer, it is common to write a "run" function that ignores it:

```
runJS :: JSmonad a -> Output
runJS ma = post $ getJSMonad ma 0
  where
    post (_,_,w) = w
```

One thing to note is that the output code is just a "log" - you cannot inspect it as you are building it, so this does limit some of the things you can do.

Answer (score 5):

It would be very difficult to use do notation without `return`. Consider the common pattern of:

```
foo = do
    x <- bar
    y <- quux
    return $ x + y
```

Without return it is impossible to define this. Recall that `>>=` has type `(>>=) :: Monad m => m a -> (a -> m b)` - it must return a value inside the monad. So even if we write this out without do notation, we have the same problem:

```
foo = bar >>= \x -> quux >>= \y -> (???????) (x + y)
```

So it's not a good idea to use do-notation for this. Particularly, there's nothing to stop the compiler implementation from introducing `return`s with transformations conforming to the monad laws (which assume the presence of `return`).

Moreover, even defining >>= will be difficult for you. How will you translate it to your imperative language? Remember that >>= takes an arbitrary function on its right argument; you are unable to inspect this function to tell what it might do, and thus cannot translate the body of this function into an imperative language. I suppose you could constrain the type of the argument to some kind of traced datatype and try to figure out the *effects* of the function, but now this means the function can't inspect its argument. In short, it's just not going to work very well.

One alternate approach you might consider is to create a Monad that represents the process of building an imperative function. It might, for example, look like this:

```
emitAddAndPrint varA varB = do
    varTmp <- allocateTempVariable
    emitOp (Add varTmp varA varB)
-- if you want to be fancy, emitOp (varTmp :=: varA :+: varB) or something
    emitCall "print" [varTmp]
```

Comment: However,
return x
also allows the introduction of any value x, i.e. one not defined in the do body. I hoped to only allow return values that are associated with valid variable bindings in the output language - i.e. the values there are available at any point in the do block corresponds with a variable binding in the generated code.

Comment: I don't quite get the reasons for which it wouldn't work very well. Perhaps I could provide more details: my type for the near-monad is very similar to the state monad: newtype JsMonad a = JsMonad ( JsState -> ( a , JsState ) ). For (>>=) :: m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b --- the second argument can produce another JsMonad, which is then composed with the first monad.

Comment: I guess I have a hard time understanding why you'd want to restrict it to variable bindings unless `>>=` is inspecting the return values, at which point the question is why?

Comment: Javascript code: "var a_1 = 20;". Haskell code to generate the code: "x <- def (Js.IntL 20)", and x is now of type "m Js.IntL". Js code: "var a_2 = function(x,y) { x + y; }". Haskell to generate the code: "sum <- ...", sum is now of type "m (Js.IntL -> Js.IntL -> m Js.IntE)". To call sum, Haskell code: "sum x x", which is associated with the Js code: "a_2(x,x)". (L,E shorthand for Literal and Expression).

Comment: In a sense, I'd like to attach Javascript variables / expressions with type information from Haskell. If there's no variable / expression that results, there is no need to return any value. All other code-generating functions can be defined outside of the monad.

Comment: Correction to previous previous comment: To call sum, Haskell code: "sum x x", which is associated with the Js code: "a_2(a_1,a_1)".

Comment: So you're using the monad-wrapped type as a type constraint to prevent bad code from being generated, rather than as an actual value?

Comment: Yes to the first part, and as a kind of macro/template system for Javascript.

Comment: Hmm, not sure if that can be shoehorned onto a monad then. This is the sort of type hackery where you'll be off on your own I guess - but see camccann's answer for rebindable syntax I guess

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly, the most sensible interpretation of `return` here would be to insert a literal value without binding it to an identifier, which would make sense in some contexts but simply `x <- return 1` doesn't seem to be meaningful.

Comment: Hm... I could define the return as cmc suggested, and have another type/class that indicates whether that type is bound to a variable for safety. It would be useful: I would have a return and a monad (and a simpler do notation), with the option to structure multiple identifier names returned in a Haskell type (as opposed to putting them into a Js structure, binding it to a Js identifier, then returning that identifier). At the moment, I still can't think of any other reasons for returning arbitrary haskell types. Any meta-information can be carried in the Js code as well.

Comment: @b: You're right that I wouldn't be able to do "foo = do { x <- bar ; y <- quux ; return $ x + y }" without return. I was thinking that I would never need to do that so I would disallow it, but on second thoughts, having a return that is valid, but (almost) never using it, doesn't seem so bad. There appears to be little loss to defining a return and making a monad, so I'll probably do just that, until I encounter problems. Thanks!

Comment: @Dingfeng Quek: Note that the example given can be written without `return` using `fmap` and `ap`, or equivalently the `Applicative` combinators, e.g. `foo = (+) <$> bar <*> quux`.

Comment: Hm... Is that guaranteed to have the same properties as return (other than the arguments it takes)? How could I show that it's identical to return?

Comment: @Dingfeng Quek: Assuming a valid instance, yes; the monad laws should be enough to show them equivalent. What it boils down to is that instead of what amounts to `m >>= (\x -> return (foo x))`, which introduces an extra layer with `return` that's immediately removed by `(>>=)`, you can just use `fmap foo m`.

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like you have an [arrow](http://www.haskell.org/arrows/).  In a monad you need to be able to write:

```
do
   x <- return $ f y
   if x then something else notSomething
```

The "if" condition gets evaluated as part of the evaluation of the "do", and the result is either "something" or "notSomething", but not both at once.  However for code generation you probably want the "if" to be translated into your generated code with both branches evaluated to produce code that can make the choice at its run-time.

The equivalent code for an arrow desugars into use of the the ArrowChoice class in which you have access to both the condition and both branches, which is what you need here.

Comment: I considered this, but based on his description of what he's doing, I'm suspicious that `arr` would be even more problematic than `return`.

Comment: Why would you use `x <- return $ f y` rather than `let x = f y`

Comment: You wouldn't do so directly, but you might very well call a function which uses "return" to construct the result, which is what bdonlan's answer is talking about.

Answer (score 3):

If you can make your type an instance of `Monad`, even with a missing `return` then the `do` notation works.  I've done it (e.g.[BASIC](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/BASIC)), and it's an excellent way to get imperative notation for a DSL.